# PHP / MySQL find duplicated records from different tables and refer from where did they come from

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, "amigos" and "socios".
In amigos I have rows id, nr_amigo, nome
In socios I have rows id, nr_socio, nome

I need to search in both tables if there are duplicated records

If I use

```
SELECT id, nr_amigo as amigo FROM amigos WHERE nome = :variavel
UNION
SELECT id, nr_socio as socio FROM socios WHERE nome = :variavel
```

It works, BUT I can't know from which table the found match has come. So my question is how do I list duplicated records (if any) and How do I know where did they came from?

In php I've

```
$sql_pesquisar -> execute($dados_a_enviar);
$num_rows_query = $sql_pesquisar -> rowCount();
if ($num_rows_query > 0) {
    while($row = $sql_pesquisar -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

Result is

```
Array
(
    [id] => 180
    [nr_amigo] => 180
)
```

But in fact that record is from "socios" and not from "amigos"

Thanks!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Downvote? Has you can see in 2 minutes I got 2 perfectly valid answers. I believe my example code was clear, but your choice.

Comment: Yep, I'm happy with my choices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another option besides the one @ascsoftw mentioned in his answer.

You can select null to the column you are not selecting in current subquery like this

```
SELECT id, nr_amigo AS amigo, NULL as socio FROM amigos WHERE nome = :variavel
UNION ALL
SELECT id, NULL AS amigo, nr_socio AS socio FROM socios WHERE nome = :variavel
```

The result will then look like

```
Array
(
    [id] => 180
    [amigo] => 180
    [socio] => null
)
```

or

```
Array
(
    [id] => 180
    [amigo] => null
    [socio] => 180
)
```

Make sure to use `UNION ALL` if you want to list duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks, I added previous answer suggestion to your like this: SELECT id, nr_amigo AS amigo, NULL as socio, 'amigos' as tabela FROM amigos WHERE nome = :variavel ... Now I can refer have different outputs, if(tabela == 'socios') print($row['socio']);

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new column as `tablename` in the `select` list to identify the table. Final query will be like

```
SELECT id, 'amigos' as tablename, nr_amigo as amigo FROM amigos WHERE nome = :variavel
UNION
SELECT id, 'socios' as tablename, nr_socio as socio FROM socios WHERE nome = :variavel
```

You can then identify using `tablename` column in php to determine which table the record belongs to.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion and added to Michal Hynčica answer, it works pretty well.